# Callback function member of polymorphic class

Tags: c++, callback, member

I am making a User Interface and the two primary classes are `UIControl` and `UIView`.
Both are abstract classes. Each view in the UI, such as the main menu etc. have UIView as parent class. I want these derived view classes to be able to assign their own member functions as callbacks for the controls. How can this be achieved?

Psuedocode below:

```
class UIControl
{
public:
    void (*m_callback_click)(int button_index, int x, int y);

    // This class also statically calls callback_click if a control is clicked
}

class UIView
{
    // Abstract class
}

class UIMainMenu : public UIView
{
public:
    UIControl* m_button1;

    void initialize();
    void button1_click(int button, int x, int y);
}

void UIMainMenu::initialize()
{
    m_button1 = new UIControl();

    m_button1->m_callback_click = &button1_click;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change

```
    static void button1_click(int button, int x, int y);
 // ^^^^^^
```

to get this to compile.

Another possibility is to declare a member function pointer in the `UIControl` class, like

```
 void (UIView::*m_callback_click)(int button_index, int x, int y);
```

---

Also ,- as @Joachim Pileborg sugessted -, prefer to manage a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object instead of holding a raw function pointer. As mentioned you can use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to assign it properly.